# ASP.NET Web API : How to authorize for static HTML content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an ASP.net Web API 2.0 project, which exposes a REST API to be consumed by a set of static HTML pages.

The HTML pages are all static content, however they should only be served to the client after proper authorization.

What is the idiomatic way to host these HTML pages in such a way that they will only be given to authorized users?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is this question about Web API or static HTML pages? You introduce Web API, then ask how to secure the static HTML. In any event, I'd probably shy away from too much security on the static HTML if you're already securing the data through Web API, just because then you can send it off to CDNs, but that's just my preference, and it depends on your business.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link to implement authorization for api controller.

> http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

OR

If you are rendering html pages without any controller than create an api controller and put the authorization on that controller.